# Weighted Frobenius norm in BFGS

Tags: optimization, quasi-newton

In what sense is the weighted Frobenius norm "adimensional"/"scale-invariant" for any symmetric positive definite weight matrix $W$? If we plug in a positive diagonal matrix into $W$ wee see that $||A||_W$ is not always $||TA||_W$ for a one-to-one transformation $T$.

See page 196 of Nocedal's book on numerical optimization and page 60 of Fletcher's "Practical methods of numerical optimization" for reference.

Comment: I don't think the claim is that this is the case for *any* weighting matrix, just for the one that actually gives rise to the BFGS update (and, possibly, not for any matrix A but just the ones obtained from BFGS updates). I think the claim is actually that the *updates* obtained from this norm are scale invariant (in the sense, e.g., of Deuflhard's "affine invariance").

Comment: Also, it's page 138 in my (second) edition of Nocedal and Wright.

Comment: Also also, [please don't cross-post](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/156): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1835397 (at least not without explicit mention).

Comment: Yes I agree they don't seem to make that claim in Nocedal and Wright. But if you see Fletcher's book (second edition) they actually do say there is some intrinsic invariance property about the weighted Frobenius norm. I have been very skeptical about that claim but it seems to get picked up in the literature [1](www.jstor.org/stable/2582880) "It is important that the measure is invariant under an affine transformation of variables (see Fletcher'), so a weighted Euclidean matrix norm of the form ... suggests itself. " However, this invariance of the norm is not mentioned anywhere in Greenstadt.

Comment: a) Don't trust claims without proof, not even in textbooks. Especially such vague statements. b) Textbooks tend to copy from each other, so no surprise there. c) The whole thing with the weighted norms is a post facto interpretation extracted from the convergence proofs and only meant to soften the blow of the various updates falling from the sky (which they did, historically) -- I am guilty of that myself when teaching nonlinear optimization.

Comment: All this is to say that the only sensible interpretation of the statement is that these quasi-Newton updates have the same scale invariance (in the sense that scaling the function, doing a Newton step, and scaling back leads to the same iterates as doing a Newton step for the original function). I don't know of any proofs of the top of my head, though. Maybe this helps: http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pabbeel/cs287-fa12/slides/NonlinearOptimizationForOptimalControl.pdf

Comment: I did find this: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1979-33-145/S0025-5718-1979-0514823-9/S0025-5718-1979-0514823-9.pdf (Section 7) and this: https://www.math.uh.edu/~rohop/fall_04/downloads/script.pdf (Section 4)

Comment: In section 3.3 of Fletcher's book he gave a simple condition for invariance. All it takes is H=T^-1HT^t  where H is the matrix approximating the inverse of the Hessian matrix. He even proved it for the DFP version of BFGS. I had no doubt about the algorithm's invariance. It is the use of the Weighted Frobenius norm that bothers me. Now can we assume it was introduced simply to move the derivation along because it gives the BFGS steps exactly if used to formulate the constrained matrix minimization problem ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I think, absent any evidence. People came up with the updates before any convergence proof, and the invariance properties came even later. (Not that I'm claiming that it's impossible to show that if $H_k$ has the the invariance property and $H_{k+1}$ minimizes $\|H_k - H\|_{WF}$ *for this specific* weighted Frobenius norm, then $H_{k+1}$ has the invariance property. It doesn't look obvious to me, though.)